# ImgAreaSelect on IE 10

Tags: jquery

I have an app using ImgAreaSelect (v0.9.10)
The issue I have it that it works fine in FF, Chrome, mac and pc. IE 10 seems to have a sporadic issue with cropping.

I cannot figure it out. When you load the image, with a preview box and then try to crop, the Cropping tool doesnt work always.  It seems very sporadic issue and only occuring on IE 10.

Here is the page code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Card Photo Upload</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/imgareaselect-default.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css" />
<style type="text/css">
#uploadForm { width: 300px; }
#uploadForm label { width: 250px; }
#uploadForm label.error, #uploadForm input.submit { margin-left: 253px; }
#uploadForm label.error {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    color:#F00;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.validate.pack.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

function preview(img, selection) {
    if (!selection.width || !selection.height)
        return;

    var scaleX = 300 / selection.width;
    var scaleY = 300 / selection.height;

    $('#preview img').css({
        width: Math.round(scaleX * <Cfoutput>#ImageData.width#</cfoutput>) + 'px',
    height: Math.round(scaleY * <Cfoutput>#ImageData.height#</cfoutput> ) + 'px',
    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px'
  });

    $('#x1').val(selection.x1);
    $('#y1').val(selection.y1);
    $('#x2').val(selection.x2);
    $('#y2').val(selection.y2);
    $('#w').val(selection.width);
    $('#h').val(selection.height);    
}

$(function () {
    $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:1', handles: true, fadeSpeed: 200, minHight: 200, minHeight: 200,  x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 200, y2: 200 ,onSelectChange: preview });

$('#photo').imgAreaSelect({ onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
            $('input[name=x1]').val(selection.x1);
            $('input[name=y1]').val(selection.y1);
            $('input[name=x2]').val(selection.x2);
            $('input[name=y2]').val(selection.y2);
       }
   });


});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<!--- SHOW IMAGE --->
<div class="container demo">

 <div style="float: left; width: 620px;">
  <p class="instructions">
   Click and drag on the image to select an area. 
  </p>

  <div class="frame" style="margin: 0 0.3em; width:<Cfoutput>#ImageData.width#</cfoutput>px">
<cfoutput>
<img src="../upload/#jpgFileName#" alt="Your Photo" id="photo" style="width=<Cfoutput>#ImageData.width#</cfoutput>px;" />
</cfoutput>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">

  <p style="font-size: 110%; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 0.1em;">
   Selection Preview
  </p>

  <div class="frame" 
   style="margin: 0 1em; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
   <div id="preview" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
   <Cfoutput>
<img src="../upload/#jpgFileName#" alt="Your Photo"  />
</Cfoutput>
   </div>
  </div>

<br />
<div class="frame" style="margin: 0pt 1em; width: 300px; ">
<form action="edit_process.cfm" id="uploadForm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit and Save</legend>


    <div class="submit-area">
        <input value="Save photo" type="submit" class="submitbutton"/>
    </div> 
    </fieldset> 
    <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="0" />  
    <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="0" />  
    <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="200" />  
    <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="200" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="img" value="<cfoutput>#jpgFileName#</cfoutput>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pik" value="<cfoutput>#url.pik#</cfoutput>" />
</form>

</div>

 </div>
</div>

<!----------------->

<cfelse>
<cfset image_error = 1>
<cflocation url="index.cfm?size">
<cfabort>
</cfif>
</body></html>
```

What would cause IE 10 to not allow the cropping to work, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how much anyone can help you with something like this.  We cannot even setup a working example since we can't see your HTML markup.  Create a concise working example that shows this issue.

Comment: More info. It appears the first time you load the image for editing, the cropping box will not work, If you leave the page and then come back to the image cropping page, the cropping tool then works.

Comment: It's all up now, I was trying to get the code to display properly

Comment: Could be anything.  What jQuery version?  Maybe the `ImgAreaSelect` plugin does not work with IE 10.  Maybe the plugin is not compatible with your version of jQuery.  Have you tried [the demo page](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) in IE 10?  What's different about the demo than your code?  Not sure how much anyone can help other than making random guesses.

Comment: Its using Jquery 1.9 directly from the download source of his plugin.
His plugin demo works with IE 10 however, none of his examples combine the preview and the coordinates save that I am doing.
it almost feels like IE 10 is not initializing the plugin properly the first load and then when you leave the page and come back it works.

Comment: Why are you calling `$('#photo').imgAreaSelect()` twice?  Why not just combine all the options into one instance?

Comment: SPARKY!!
I was trying a million things but your comment led me to an idea and I think I may have it. Will post back if I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to call `$('#photo').imgAreaSelect()` twice, so combine all options into one instance...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({
        aspectRatio: '1:1',
        handles: true,
        fadeSpeed: 200,
        minHight: 200,
        minHeight: 200,
        x1: 0,
        y1: 0,
        x2: 200,
        y2: 200,
        onSelectChange: preview,
        onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
            $('input[name=x1]').val(selection.x1);
            $('input[name=y1]').val(selection.y1);
            $('input[name=x2]').val(selection.x2);
            $('input[name=y2]').val(selection.y2);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This is what I came up with after your code, which is now working on all browsers

`code`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function preview(img, selection) {
    if (!selection.width || !selection.height)
        return;

    var scaleX = 300 / selection.width;
    var scaleY = 300 / selection.height;

    $('#preview img').css({
        width: Math.round(scaleX * <Cfoutput>#ImageData.width#</cfoutput>) + 'px',
    height: Math.round(scaleY * <Cfoutput>#ImageData.height#</cfoutput> ) + 'px',
    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px'
  });

    $('#x1').val(selection.x1);
    $('#y1').val(selection.y1);
    $('#x2').val(selection.x2);
    $('#y2').val(selection.y2);
    $('#w').val(selection.width);
    $('#h').val(selection.height);    
}
function draw(img, selection) {
            $('input[name=x1]').val(selection.x1);
            $('input[name=y1]').val(selection.y1);
            $('input[name=x2]').val(selection.x2);
            $('input[name=y2]').val(selection.y2);
       }

$(function () {
    $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:1', handles: true, fadeSpeed: 200, minHight: 200, minHeight: 200,  x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 200, y2: 200 ,onSelectChange: preview, onSelectEnd: draw });
});
</script>
```